# JSON data not showed through phone

Tags: android, json, networking, xampp, ip

Hello guys i have problem where cant display json through phone.Before i don't have this kind of problem.I already check both device using same network.Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank You.

Below Show through my laptop
[image: Below show through my laptop]Below Show through my phone

[image]

Comment: From the screenshots I can see that You have not typed the same url as you have done for the laptop. Moreover make sure your phone is in the same network as the laptop

Comment: I type http://192.168.1.105/android/notis_android.php but still got same problem and i  checked both device using same network.

Comment: if you have installed any antivirus pause it and try again..

Comment: i checked antivirus and it pause.

Answer (score 0):

You need input

```
192.168.1.105/android/notis_android.php
```

in your android browser address.

And you need to make sure your Android device and your PC have connected to the **same network**.

Comment: when using network at my place,i can access through my phone..but in the office got those kind of problem...why that happen?

Comment: @khoi Because "192.168.1.105" is a local IP address,not common address.So you can't access it in the office.

Comment: how can i get common address?

Comment: You probably put some hosts entry in your computer. You will need similar entry in your device. Try apps like [Hosts Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nilhcem.hostseditor) to accomplish this.